How to set the height or row in grid so that it adjust height according to the content
here is the image as you can see the content is going out of the box, but I want the height to be set according to the content in short, the height should be dynamic.
I have tried using grid-template-rows: auto auto; still getting same issue. how to fix this issue so that each time the height is set according to the content.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0.8cm;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " / " counter(pages);
    font-size: 10px;
    color: black;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.big {
  font-size: 14px;
}

p {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.section-3 {
  word-break: break-all;
}

.section-3-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65% 17.5% 17.5%;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.state-info,
.pan-info {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-1 {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-3 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-4 {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="section-3">
  <div class="section-3-body">
    <div class="item-1">
      <div class="consignee-info">
        <div class="consignee-header">
          <p>
            <strong>Consignee:</strong>
            <span class="big fw-bold">B.K. Enterprises (Delhi)</span>
          </p>
          <p>
            <strong>Address:</strong>
            <span>
                  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNQWERTYUI
                </span>
          </p>
          <div class="state-info">
            <p><strong>State:</strong> <span>Delhi</span></p>
            <p><strong>State code:</strong> <span>07</span></p>
            <p><strong>Phone no :</strong> <span>9311142406</span></p>
          </div>

          <div class="pan-info">
            <p><strong>PAN:</strong> <span>ABFPN3214M</span></p>
            <p><strong>GST No:</strong> <span>07ABFPN3214M1ZM</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
      <div class="transport-name">
        <p>
          <strong>Transport Name:</strong>
          <br />
          <span>JAIPUR GOLDEN JAIPUR GOLDEN JAIPUR GOLDEN JAIPUR</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-3">
      <div class="lr-wrapper">
        <div class="lr-vech-no">
          <p>
            <strong>LR/Vehicle Name:</strong>
            <br />
            <span>QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDAZ</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-4">
      <div class="lr-vech-date">
        <p>
          <strong>LR/Vehicle Date:</strong>
          <br />
          <span>24-JULY-2024</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




i like to add that i am using weasyprint for converting HTML file to pdf, getting issue there

TLDR
Your code is fine. You are doing the right thing to set the height of a row so it adjusts based on the amount of content. The issue is with Weasyprint itself.
Full Explanation and Possible Approaches
As you have seemingly noticed (based on your comment "i like to add that i am using weasyprint for converting HTML file to pdf, getting issue there" that you added to your question) the code you have provided works fine in the browser but not when Weasyprint does its conversion. As such the issue is not so much with your code but with Weasyprint's ability to deal with it correctly, as a browser would.
Weasyprint seems to have a number of limitations regarding grid features it supports / doesn't support / hasn't tested (you can read each of those limitations in their docs via that link).
Two of the unsupported / untested features that could be causing the issue you are experiencing are as follows:

"auto content size for grid containers"
"span for flexible tracks"

As Weasyprint don't differentiate between unsupported and untested features it is worth trying to get round the issues. There are a couple of things you can therefore try:
In .item-1 change the line grid-row: 1 / span 2; to grid-row: 1 / 3;. This is in an effort to deal with the second point above (i.e. "span for flexible tracks"). By doing this we are still telling .item-1 to span the first two rows, we are just using a different value to do so.
If you are still experiencing the same issue after that then we know auto sizing based on amount of content is a problem. There is really only one way round that and that is to explicitly set the height of the rows. Obviously this is not ideal as you don't know how much content will be in each item so you'd really need to set the height of each row based on the maximum amount of content you are likely to have to place in the items. To do that you would need to change grid-template-rows: auto auto; in .section-3-body to something like grid-template-rows: 100px 100px; (change 100px to whatever is a sensible size for your use case).
If it turns out that auto content size is unsupported rather than simply untested (you will know this once you eliminate the span possibility) you can request new features from Weasyprint. The information on how to do so can be found via this link.
If setting an explicit height on rows is not something you could feasibly do you will have to resort to using flex to build your layout which is a shame as 2 dimensional layouts are very much a job for grid not flex. Nonetheless I have built a version of your layout in codepen using flex which you can get at via this link.

I am using currently playwright to convert html to pdf. Do anybody know by chance how to add page border to all pages of the pdf
